# Си: показатель загрузки

Tags: c, linux, gentoo

Как в `emerge` сделан вращающийся слеш? (`/`) Он пишет:

`Calculating dependencies /`

И слеш вращается. Как это сделано? Хочу повторить.

Comment: Наверное каждый раз перепечатывается одна и та же строка, только меняется один символ: -,\,|,/

Comment: Да. Но только это все делается на одном месте...

Comment: Думаю последовательно, в одной и той же позиции с небольшой задержкой выводите в цикле символы /-\|

Comment: @egordorichev можно при выводе в консоль управлять кареткой с помощью символа '\r' 


        printf("hello");
        printf("\rbye");

Comment: Спасибо! Переделайте в ответ, пожалуйста!

Comment: @egordorichev done

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Я практически уверен, что они (emerge) делают это так (а не \r и вывод всей строки, что вызывало бы некую рябь на экране)

Можете попробовать и поиграться задержкой (usleep)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int 
main (int ac, char *av[])
{
  int i, j;
  char *s = "/-\\|";

  fputs("test  ", stdout); fflush(stdout);
  for (i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    for (j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
      printf("\b%c", s[j]); fflush(stdout); // символ \b -- BACKSPACE -- шаг назад
      usleep(100000);
    }

}
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное! То, что нужно!

Answer (score 6):

Если нужно перепечатывать только один символ - достаточно \b печатать - смещает курсор на 1 позицию назад.

Answer (score 1):

Наверное каждый раз перепечатывается одна и та же строка, только меняется один символ: -,\,|,/ –

можно при выводе в консоль управлять кареткой с помощью символа '\r'

```
printf("hello"); 
printf("\rbye");
```